# Code Signing Certificate for Sole Proprietor

Tags: code-signing

I've been selling my software Isadora (https://troikatronix.com) for 17 years, and I would like to start code signing the app and installer.

I've been turned down by three code signing certificate vendors because I'm a Sole Proprietor in Germany where the concept of DBA doesn't exist. Since there is no corporation or organization, they won't issue me a certificate.

Has anyone here succeeded in purchasing a code signing certificate as a independent developer? (Extra points if you live in Germany)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you register yourself in Dun & Bradstreet. Your full name, physical address and phone number should be registered there and a CA can issue you a Standard Code Signing Certificate. But if you want a EV Code signing certificate, its not going to be easy.

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking into this but I'm here in the US. I'm currently a sole proprietor and if you search for my DBA company name in Dunn and Bradstreet, it comes up with my personal name, not my company name. As such, Comodo wants to issue a cert with my name, not my business. They suggested I get a legal opinion letter from either an accountant or attorney, which I have yet to do. Here is the link for Comodo. Perhaps you can go through this route.

https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1231/0/sample-legal-opinion-letters-for-ev-certificates

Answer (score 0):

I'm from Poland and recently changed from an LLC to a sole proprietorship. While buying an EV cert for an LLC is extremely easy, getting one for a sole proprietorship is extremely difficult. DigiCert told me one can obtain an EV certificate as sole proprietorship only if he/she registered under a trade name. So, if you registered under your real name, you won't be able to get an EV cert.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also going through this process and it's confusing. Sectigo support is pretty poor.

I've been told that as a Sole Proprietor, in order for me to have my business name attached to the certificate, my company would need to be incorporated even if I have registered a DBA name. My assumption is that because as a sole proprietor, even if you have a registered DBA name, the legal entity is still the individual.

Kind of annoying that nobody really talks about this prior to purchasing a certificate. The other option is to do an individual cert which will be attached to my name rather than my business.